# Improving asynchronous execution in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am currently writing a programme that performs large simulations on the GPU using the CUDA API. In order to accelerate the performance, I tried to run my kernels simultaneously and then asynchronously copy the result into the host memory again. The code looks roughly like this:

```
#define NSTREAMS   8
#define BLOCKDIMX  16
#define BLOCKDIMY  16

void domainUpdate(float* domain_cpu,       // pointer to domain on host
                  float* domain_gpu,       // pointer to domain on device
                  const unsigned int dimX,
                  const unsigned int dimY,
                  const unsigned int dimZ)
{
    dim3 blocks((dimX + BLOCKDIMX - 1) / BLOCKDIMX, (dimY + BLOCKDIMY - 1) / BLOCKDIMY);
    dim3 threads(BLOCKDIMX, BLOCKDIMY);

    for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < NSTREAMS; ++ii) {

        updateDomain3D<<<blocks,threads, 0, streams[ii]>>>(domain_gpu,
                                                           dimX, 0,  dimX - 1, // dimX, minX, maxX
                                                           dimY, 0,  dimY - 1, // dimY, minY, maxY
                                                           dimZ, dimZ * ii / NSTREAMS,  dimZ * (ii + 1) / NSTREAMS - 1); // dimZ, minZ, maxZ

        unsigned int offset = dimX * dimY * dimZ * ii / NSTREAMS;
        cudaMemcpyAsync(domain_cpu + offset ,
                        domain_gpu+ offset ,
                        sizeof(float) * dimX * dimY * dimZ / NSTREAMS,
                        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, streams[ii]);
    }

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

All in all it is just a simple for-loop, looping over all streams (8 in this case) and dividing the work. This actually is a deal faster (up to 30% performance gain), although maybe less than I had hoped. I analysed a typical cycle in Nvidia's Compute Visual Profiler, and the execution looks like this:

[image: CUDA API trace in the Compute Visual Profiler]

As can be seen in the picture, the kernels do overlap, although never more than two kernels are running at the same time. I tried the same thing for different numbers of streams and different sizes of the simulation domain, but this is always the case.

So my question is: is there a way to encourage/force the GPU scheduler to run more than two things at the same time? Or is this a limitation dependent on the GPU device that cannot be represented in the code?

My system specifications are: 64-bit Windows 7, and a GeForce GTX 670 graphics card (that's Kepler architecture, compute capability 3.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernels overlap only if the GPU has resources left to run a second kernel. Once the GPU is fully loaded, there is no gain from running more kernels in parallel, so the driver does not do that.

Comment: But even with a very small kernel, like a number of blocks, never more than 2 kernels run at the same time. So physical size of the GPU can't be the whole story, can it?

Comment: Yes, it can.  What's a "small kernel"?  How many blocks?  How many threads per block?  Do they use shared memory?  Registers?  Unless you've analyzed the resource utilization of a kernel, you won't know how many can be run.  Windows (when GPU is in WDDM mode) can also interfere with concurrency by batching GPU activity.  The GPU is not limited to running two things at the same time.

Comment: That's a good point, I hadn't quite thought about all the shared memory and register requirements, and I don't quite understand to what extend this influences performance.

A 'small' kernel I tried is for example 8x8 blocks with 16x16 threads. Of those, loads more should theoretically fit on the GPU, I'd say. It uses 33 registers per thread about 2 kB of shared memory per block. Is that a lot?

Comment: Use the Occupancy Calculator to find out how many blocks can run concurrently on one multiprocessor. In case of your kernel it's 6 blocks/SMX, so the 7 SMX of a GTX 670 can run 42 blocks concurrently. With a grid of 64 blocks, the first wave of concurrent blocks will leave 22 blocks to be processed in the second wave, leaving space for another 20 blocks if the same kernel is launched a second time (but not enough for a third launch). Perfectly explains your findings from the profiler.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, that makes a lot more sense now!